# circuitikz - how to change only the color of a bipole

Tags: circuitikz

I'd like to solely change the color of the bipole (and, if possible, also of the line). The labels as well as the current arrow should stay black. Is there any possibility to achive this? In the following MWE, the current arrow is still red, which is unwanted.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european,cuteinductors,fetbodydiode,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, arrowmos]
        \draw [color=red] (0,0) to[R,R=\textcolor{black}{$R_1$}, i_=\textcolor{black}{$i_1$}, bipole current append style={color=black}] (4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See page 215 of the circuitikz manual.

Comment: So you suggest `\draw [] (0,0) to[R,color=red,R=$R_1$, i_=$i_1$] (4,0);` which does not work (the current arrow is still red)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533927/colored-element-with-black-connections-in-circuitikz/533966#533966  -- combined with -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565089/coloring-components-and-customizing-voltages-in-circuitikz/565104#565104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can suppress the output of the current symbol and add it manually afterward.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european,cuteinductors,fetbodydiode,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, arrowmos]
        \draw [color=red] (0,0) to[R,l=\textcolor{black}{$R_1$},
           i_=\textcolor{black}{$i_1$}, no i symbols, name=blah] (4,0);
        \node[currarrow] at (blah-Ipos) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, there is no need to add rotation, but if needed, there is an example in the manual on page 207 (notice that page *will* change with different versions of the manual):

[image]

So, for example:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european,cuteinductors,fetbodydiode,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, arrowmos]
        \draw [color=red] (0,0) to[R,l=\textcolor{black}{$R_1$},
           i_=\textcolor{black}{$i_1$}, no i symbols, name=blah] (4,0) 
           to[R,l=\textcolor{black}{$R_2$},
           i_=\textcolor{black}{$i_2$}, no i symbols, name=blah2] (7,3);
        \node[currarrow] at (blah-Ipos) {};
        \node[currarrow, rotate=\ctikzgetdirection{blah2-Iarrow}] at (blah2-Ipos) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you use this a lot, probably a macro like the one in the manual's example is better:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european,cuteinductors,fetbodydiode,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
%%% "fc" mnemonics: fixed color
\newcommand\textfc[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\newcommand\fcI[1]{\node[currarrow,
    rotate=\ctikzgetdirection{#1-Iarrow}] at (#1-Ipos) {}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, arrowmos]
        \draw [color=red] (0,0) to[R=\textfc{$R_1$},
           i_=\textfc{$i_1$}, no i symbols, name=blah] (4,0) 
           to[R,l=\textfc{$R_2$},
           i_=\textfc{$i_2$}, no i symbols, name=blah2] (7,3);
        \fcI{blah};
        \fcI{blah2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

...and as a bonus, if you decide to have the text, say, blue, you have to change it just in one place.

Comment: Thanks, however, as you already noted, I also have bipoles with rotation. The rotation is not set by a fixed angle but is given by the two coordinates that the bipole connects. I have not seen an example on page 206 of the circuitikz manual 1.6.3 but I tried to add the rotation=... which works but is cumbersome because I'd have to try around a lot to get the correct degree value.

Comment: @Steradiant for that there is the `\ctikzgetdirection{}` macro that returns the rotation angle of the bipole... see my update.